# Should I synchronize ObjectOutputStream.writeObject(Object)?

Tags: java, multithreading, concurrency, io, objectoutputstream

I have a server with multiple clients. It uses one server socket and two thread pools for receiving and handling requests from remote clients: one pool - for handling clients connections, and another one - for processing clients remote tasks. Each client sends asynchronous tasks with unique task ID (within each connection) and a bunch of parameters. Upon task deserialization, the server looks up the corresponding service, invokes the given method on it, wraps the result along with the task ID into the answer object and sends it back to the client using `ObjectOutputStream`.

Since tasks are handled concurrently, two or more threads might finish processing tasks for one client at the same time and try to compete for the `ObjectOutputStream`.

What happens next? I mean, do they write their objects to output stream atomically or should I synchronize their access to `ObjectOutputStream`, so that to avoid situation when one thread writes half of its object - then another thread intervenes and... as a result, a sort of Frankenstein object will be send to the client.

```java
import java.io.*;
import java.lang.reflect.Method;
import java.net.ServerSocket;
import java.net.Socket;
import java.util.*;
import java.util.concurrent.*;

public class Server {

    private final ExecutorService connExecutor = Executors.newCachedThreadPool();  
    private final ExecutorService tasksExecutor = Executors.newCachedThreadPool(); 

    public void start() {
        try (ServerSocket socket = new ServerSocket(2323);) {
            while (true) {
                try (Socket conn = socket.accept()) {
                    connExecutor.execute(() -> {
                        try (ObjectInputStream in = new ObjectInputStream(conn.getInputStream());
                             ObjectOutputStream out = new ObjectOutputStream(conn.getOutputStream())) {
                            while (true) {
                                RemoteTask task = (RemoteTask) in.readObject();
                                tasksExecutor.execute(() -> {
                                    handleTask(task, out);
                                });
                            }
                        } catch (IOException | ClassNotFoundException e) {
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        }
                    });
                }
            }
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    private void handleTask(RemoteTask task, ObjectOutputStream out) {
        RemoteAnswer answer = new RemoteAnswer();
        // unwrap remote task 
        // lookup local service 
        // invoke task's method
        // wrap result into remote answer

        // send answer to the client 
        try {
            out.writeObject(answer);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Yes. The method isn't synchronized, so you should synchronize it yourself.

Comment: And just for the record: you understand that "built in" java serialization is like year 2000 technology, and not something that many folks would be using for a new product in 2019?

Comment: @GhostCatsaysReinstateMonica, could you please give me a hint or direction as to alternative approaches for serialization. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

This [here](http://www.jguru.com/faq/view.jsp?EID=44251) says it nicely:

> Is writing an object to an ObjectOutputStream a thread-safe operation?
>
> **Absolutely not**.

So, yes, **your** code needs to take precautions itself.

Comment: Now, I got confused a little. It's said passing an object reference to the `writeObject()` is not an atomic operation, so _if other threads are allowed to concurrently access or modify any of the objects in the graph_ while the object is being serialized, then the object's state might lose its consistency. But what happens if two threads pass **immutable** or **thread-confined** objects in a shared `ObjectOutputStream`?

Comment: Assume, two threads share a common `ObjectOutputStream`, and both try to write in parallel two **immutable** objects (thread A writes object A1, thread B writes object B1). Does this create possibility that objects A1 and B1 somehow might "merge", or in any case they will be written into underlying `OutputStream` separately: first goes A1, then B1 (maybe, vise versa). If so, then I don't understand why should I use synchronization in my code if each task is handled in their own thread creating its own local answer object, which is never modified by other threads?

Comment: @escudero380 it doesn’t matter whether your objects are immutable, the `ObjectOutputStream` is not. Writing an object to the stream will modify its internal state and it’s not thread safe. Hence, you have to synchronize. And deal with the possibility that the answers may be send in a different order than the questions…

Answer (score 0):

As a rule of thumb: If the documentation doesn't specify that a certain class is thread-safe, it probably isn't. Thread-safety clearly is an "intentional quality" (allusion to [Roman Elizarov's blog post](https://medium.com/@elizarov/intentional-qualities-7e6a57bb87fc), one of Kotlin's language designers) and should therefore always be mentioned.

However, if you're still unsure whether a class of the Java SE-library provides thread-safety or not (as it might be mentioned somewhere else, e.g. the superclass' documentation), you might also just take a quick glance at the type's source code. [As you can see](https://github.com/openjdk-mirror/jdk7u-jdk/blob/master/src/share/classes/java/io/ObjectOutputStream.java), `ObjectOutputStream` doesn't implement any synchronization mechanisms.